# Day and Year got swapped SSIS and SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ssis, datetime-format

I got strange issue between SSIS and SQL Server.

I've developed SSIS to read CSV flat files and upload the files to SQL Server. Everything is working great and perfectly. The strange issue is that out of 1000 records that SSIS is importing 200 records have an issue with date where the date data are getting swapped the day became in the place of the year and the year in place of the day.

This is an example of perfect row and problematic row

Perfect row:

```
2018-12-17 09:05:00.000
```

Problematic row:

```
2017-12-18 09:05:00.000
```

Anyone faced the same issue or knows how to solve  please assist.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following steps supported me to sort out the issue:

1. Set the PC format to be dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss
2. Open the CSV file and try to expand the columns which is having the issue.
3. Close the CSV file and save the changes.

and run the SSIS.

Hope that will help you too

Comment: ["Don’t use global state to manage a local problem"](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20081211-00/?p=19873)

Answer (score 0):

Just try to convert the date format while loading into tables in ssis/after loading into table just update the records into a proper datetime format using convert function in backend.

In Csv itself getting mixed format in the sense just push it into staging table and split up the problematic records and correct the source data.

Comment: Thanks Mani for your response. Converting manually is working fine. But i am looking for a permanent fix where there will be no human intervention..

Comment: Have u checked the source file?what data type have u used in ssis and sql?

Comment: thanks i figure out the solution. the issue is that the csv file is reading PC format and i have set the foramt to be dd-mm-yyyy instead of dd-mm-yy.

Comment: Awesome.Have u used expression for changing the format or in sql code?