# How to swap day and month SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, date, date-format, swap

I have a column called reading_date and it is defined as datetime. I have many records in it and I could figure out that there are many records where the day is in the month and the vise versa. **For e.g 2019-05-01 which it should be 2019-01-05**. is there any way to swap and fix such issue. I am using SQL Server.
Thanks in advance

Comment: How can you tell if 05-01 should be 01-05?

Comment: Forget about swapping. Your first goal is to find those rows where you think the date is incorrect. How do you propose to do that? By looking at the values? You mention dates in 2019 - but what about dates that have already passed? If the problem is occurring now, it is likely, perhaps highly likely, that the issue exists with older data. So maybe the first thing to do is figure out what process/app/logic is inserting faulty data and fix it first. A trigger might help temporarily prevent this in order to give you time.

Comment: And we see now that you had this same problem [a few weeks ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53902097/day-and-year-got-swapped-ssis-and-sql-server) where you claimed to have fixed. So you probably do have older data that is incorrect. Looking for dates > the current date will probably not find all the problems.

Comment: i have identified the records which is affected. it is around 8000 records.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Split dates using [DATEPART](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function and gather them in another way using [DATEFROMPARTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datefromparts-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

```
UPDATE yourtable 
SET yourdate = 
  DATEFROMPARTS(
    DATEPART(year, [yourdate]),
    DATEPART(day, [yourdate]),  
    DATEPART(month, [yourdate]))
WHERE ...
```